# Wie wird der Name Eliena ausgesprochen

Tags: pronunciation

Wie wird der Name Eliena richtig ausgesprochen.
Eli-ena oder Elina nur mit langgezogenen "I"

Könnte man es so und so aussprechen?

Vielen Dank

Comment: Vielleicht so: https://de.howtopronounce.com/eliena

Answer (score 3):

Rein von der Schreibweise sind beide Möglichkeiten gegeben.

Für Namen gelten im Allgemeinen ohnehin "Sonderregeln". Auf die Spitze getrieben, haben es da die [Eltern Musk](https://www.washingtonpost.com/technology/2020/05/08/musk-grimes-baby-name/).

Eliena selbst ist verwandt mit den Schreibweisen Elina oder Eliina. Beides lässt eher auf eine Aussprache mit langem i statt i-e vermuten. Letztendlich ist dies aber auch kein "Beleg" oder gar ein Gesetz. Die Eltern bzw das Kind selbst werden am Ende festlegen, wie der Name auszusprechen sei.